# How to drop delimiter in hive table

Tags: r, hive

1. I download the file using download.file function in R
2. Save it locally
3. Move it to HDFS

My hive table is mapped to this location of file in HDFS. Now, this file has `,` as the delimiter/separator which I cannot change using download.file function from R.

There is a field that has `,` in its content. How do I tell hive to drop this delimiter if found anywhere within the field contents?
I understand we can change the delimiter but is there really a way I can drop it like sqoop allows us to do?

My R script is as simple as

```
download.file()
hdfs.put
```

Is there a workaround?

Comment: What's the structure of the file you downloaded? Is it a CSV? In that case, could you show a few lines of the file?

Comment: So you have a field that happens to contain a delimiter character. This is a sign of **bad design**. Find the person who did the mistake and try to convince him/her to *(a)* use a more suitable delimiter (such as `TAB` or `|` or whatever has very little probability of being contained in a free text label); failing that, *(b)* filter the field contents when generating the file so that `,` character is replaced by sthg different but resembling a comma; *(c)* failing that, enclose all fields in quotes so that delimiters are clearly identified. Failing that, have him/her fired.